# Protractor - try to click an element and ignore all errors

Tags: typescript, exception, protractor

I want to try to click an ElementFinder, so that in case of error during click, the tests will be not marked as failed and no error will be placed on console.

Unfortunately, my method:

```
static tryToClick(elem: ElementFinder) {
    // I want to ignore all errors, just try to click and if not proceed
    if (elem.isPresent() && elem.isDisplayed() && elem.isEnabled()) {
        try {
          browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elem), 999).then(function() {
            elem.click().then(function() {try {} catch (error) {} } );
          });
        } catch (error) {}
    }
  }
```

still produces an error on the console:

> - Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

thus I don't understand why it is not handled in the try-catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `try-catch` isn't working, because the error occurs inside the promise.

There are three ways to catch promise rejection:

1. Use the `.catch(...)` function of a promise

   ```
   elem.click().catch((err) => { // Do some error handling stuff in here });
   ```
2. Use the rejection-function of the `.then(...)`

   ```
   elem.click().then(() => {
       // Do something
   }, (err) => {
       //Do some error handling stuff in here
   });
   ```
3. Use a `try-catch` in combination with `async-await`

   ```
   static async tryToClick(elem: ElementFinder) {
       // I want to ignore all errors, just try to click and if not proceed
       if (elem.isPresent() && elem.isDisplayed() && elem.isEnabled()) {
           try { 
               await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elem), 999);
               await elem.click();
           } catch (error) {}
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't there also be `await`'s for the other element methods, such as `isPresent()`?

Comment: It's possible, but not mandatory, except the error occurs in the if-condition.

Comment: Unfortunately test is marked as failed: `Failed: elem.click(...).catch is not a function`.

Comment: Another solution is to use .isPresent() cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25346441/636849

Comment: You need to have `element.click(...).then().catch` You won't be able to access the catch method directly from click.